# ggplot to table in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I reverse the process the code for ggplot?
Suppose for any dataset, I have made a ggplot. Now how can I reverse this process. i.e., from a ggplot I want to make a matrix/table.

Let's say my dataset looks like this:

```
ID  A   B    Act
1   12  12   A
1   13  18   B
1   15  11   A
1   12  12   A
1   13  10   c
1   16  17   A
1   18  16   A
1   17  17   B
1   20  11   c
```

I used this command for ggplot:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(df, aes(y = A, x = B, colour = Act), pch = 17) +
geom_point()
```

Now, once I have a ggplot, How can I produce a table out of it using ggplot?

Answer (score 3):

You can save your ggplot in a local variable (e.g. `plot`) and use the `data` property of this variable (e.g. `plot$data`):

```
library("ggplot2")
df <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1, 9), 
  A = c(12, 13, 15, 12, 13, 16, 18, 17, 20), 
  B = c(12, 18, 11, 12, 10, 17, 16, 17, 11), 
  Act = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B", "C"))
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(y = A, x = B, colour = Act), pch = 17) + geom_point()
data <- plot$data
data
#  ID  A  B Act
# 1  1 12 12   A
# 2  1 13 18   B
# 3  1 15 11   A
# 4  1 12 12   A
# 5  1 13 10   C
# 6  1 16 17   A
# 7  1 18 16   A
# 8  1 17 17   B
# 9  1 20 11   C
```

You can observe the full `ggplot` structure via `str(plot)`:

```
str(plot)
# List of 9
#  $ data       :'data.frame':    9 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ ID : num [1:9] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#   ..$ A  : num [1:9] 12 13 15 12 13 16 18 17 20
#   ..$ B  : num [1:9] 12 18 11 12 10 17 16 17 11
#   ..$ Act: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 2 3
#  $ layers     :List of 1
#   ..$ :Classes 'proto', 'environment' <environment: 0x00000000187ac768> 
#  $ scales     :Reference class 'Scales' [package "ggplot2"] with 1 fields
#   ..$ scales: list()
#   ..and 21 methods, of which 9 are possibly relevant:
#   ..  add, clone, find, get_scales, has_scale, initialize, input, n, non_position_scales
#  $ mapping    :List of 3
#   ..$ x     : symbol B
#   ..$ y     : symbol A
#   ..$ colour: symbol Act
#  $ theme      : list()
#  $ coordinates:List of 1
#   ..$ limits:List of 2
#   .. ..$ x: NULL
#   .. ..$ y: NULL
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "cartesian" "coord"
#  $ facet      :List of 1
#   ..$ shrink: logi TRUE
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "null" "facet"
#  $ plot_env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#  $ labels     :List of 3
#   ..$ x     : chr "B"
#   ..$ y     : chr "A"
#   ..$ colour: chr "Act"
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
```